# Calculated column with date and number, either but not both can be null, as part of PK

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a table created in 1990 (yes, 27 years ago) that has a surrogate PK and lots of duplicate rows.  I'm migrating the table from Access to SQL Server, and I've dropped the surrogate key field, but I'm trying to figure out how to include a calculated column from two source columns which can contain null values.
This works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActionHistory]
(
    [Position Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SSN] [nvarchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [Action] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,

    [EffectiveSalaryKey] AS  (CONVERT([varchar](20), [Action Effective Date], 20) + ';' + 
                              CONVERT([varchar](20), isnull([Salary], ''), 0)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [Action Effective Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Salary] [money] NULL,
    ...,
    [entered] [datetime] NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_ActionHistory_entered]  DEFAULT (getdate()),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ActionHistory] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Position Number] ASC, [SSN] ASC, [Action] ASC, [EffectiveSalaryKey] ASC)
    ...
)
```

but it doesn't allow me to enter rows with null effective dates.

I want to do something like convert null dates to blanks for the key field, or even a static value like `1/1/1900 00:00:00`, but I can't get the syntax right.

I've tried adding `isnull(date,'')` before the conversion to `varchar`, after the conversion, and after appending the delimiter, but they didn't work, and I also tried adding `isnull(date,'1900-01-01 00:00:00')` but that didn't work either.

When I try:

```
[EffectiveSalaryKey]  AS 
    (
        CONVERT(
            [varchar](20),isnull([Action Effective Date],''),20
                )
```

it says:

```
Computed column 'EffectiveSalaryKey' in table 'ActionHistory' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.
```

I'm doing this with script, outside the GUI, as I understand there's a bug in there for this type of assignment.  I also understand the style must be supplied when converting from date to varchar.

Please let me know how I should append these field values so I can use the calculated column as part of the PK.

Thanks,

-Beth

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to stop storing SSN in plain text. Not only is it incredibly irresponsible it is illegal in many states. And some states have legal precedents that they can hold you liable if you have this type of information that is breached even if you do not do business in that state. Massachusetts is one such state. SSN needs to salted and hashed. It needs to be encrypted at all times.

Comment: actually, there are a lot of things I 'should' do with this data, but right now, I'm focused on moving it to another back end where RI is enforced.

Comment: Well using SSN in clear text as part of a primary key is just awful. I sure hope my data is nowhere near this system. I feel your pain about business forcing you to stick to the task at hand but seriously, this is fraught with problems and anything you do that involves maintaining this type of data is work that at some point will have to be fixed because it is flawed beyond repair. Encrypting that data should be priority one as your company is at risk for a number of legal reasons. I would send this up the flag pole and suggest they speak with a lawyer. I am not kidding. It is this serious.

Comment: just so you know, this data is only used internally.  It isn't shared anywhere, so they haven't been concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a surrogate key on this table as well, and supplement with a unique index. (along with replacing spaces in column names with underscores)

For your computed column, I think this is what you are after:

```
  , effectivesalarykey  as (
      isnull(convert(varchar(20),[action_effective_date],20)+ ';','')
      + isnull(convert(varchar(20),salary),'0')
    ) persisted not null
```

You can change the first `''` in the first `isnull` to whatever you like

```
  , effectivesalarykey  as (
      isnull(convert(varchar(20),[action_effective_date],20)+ ';','1900-01-01 00:00:00;')
      + isnull(convert(varchar(20),salary),'0')
    ) persisted not null
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/SBA4540

```
create table dbo.actionhistory(
    id int not null identity(1,1)
  , position_number int not null
  , ssn nvarchar(11) not null
  , action nvarchar(10) not null
  , effectivesalarykey  as (
      isnull(convert(varchar(20),[action_effective_date],20)+ ';','')
      + isnull(convert(varchar(20),salary),'0')
      ) persisted not null
  , 
    [action_effective_date] datetime null
  , salary money null
  , entered datetime null constraint df_actionhistory_entered  default (getdate())
  , constraint pk_actionhistory primary key clustered (id)
);

create unique nonclustered index ix_actionhistory_position_ssn_action_effectivesalarykey 
  on dbo.actionhistory (
      position_number asc
    , ssn asc
    , action asc
    , effectivesalarykey asc )


insert into dbo.actionhistory (position_number,ssn,action) values 
(1,'000-00-0000','Test')

select * 
from dbo.actionhistory;
```

results:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | position_number |     ssn     | action | effectivesalarykey | action_effective_date | salary |       entered       |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |               1 | 000-00-0000 | Test   |                  0 | NULL                  | NULL   | 13.02.2017 20:35:21 |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I swear I tried that, but I think it was within the GUI.  The idea was to leave the fields alone so I wouldn't break the downstream dependencies in queries, forms, and reports, so for now, I'm not worried about it.  I have another table with worse problems to migrate.  Thanks for your help, it's working now.